# Can't upgrade to java ee 7 'cause Atmosphere stops working

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt, atmosphere

I'm upgrading a `java ee 6` project to `7`. It's a gwt web application using `Atmosphere` to do some little instant messaging. As moving to `java ee 7`, I can't run the webapp in debug mode anymore, I got this exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to createclass org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:437)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:616)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServerContainer is null
at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.<init>(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:43)
... 33 more
```

If I configure the eclipse web project back to java ee 6 it works fine. I'm using `Eclipse Kepler`, `Atmosphere 2.1.6` and `gwt 2.5.1`.

Comment: I'm not sure what `Atmosphere 2.1.6` is used for, but what I know from the GWT Release notes (http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_0) is that until GWT 2.6 it supports Java 1.6 - I suspect that it is the compatibility issue between GWT & Java!

Comment: @BPavanKumar maybe the gwt-plugin embedded jetty is too old?